# How can I create a new playframework 2.3 application?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm not ready for JVM 1.8 yet so I want to create a 2.3.10 application. How do I do it?

Comment: This seed uses play 2.3; https://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/play-java-2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seed uses play 2.3; [typesafe.com/activator/template/play-java-2.3](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-java-2.3)

You can use `activator new PROJECTNAME play-java-2.3` command to use this seed.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can download previous versions of the Play framework at https://www.playframework.com/download#older-versions